# Java: Reading CSV file to take min, max, average of various stats

Tags: java, csv

I want to write a Java class that will take a CSV file and take the min, max, average, etc... of various statistics. Please see below for a sample of this file. For example, I want to get the stats for "Opening login page", "Logging in as lead user", etc..

I have started by reading TestName and Time into a Map:

```
static Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
...
for (String line : file) {
if (line.contains("Test Name")){
//Get next line, this is the first one.
continue;
}
String TestName = (line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","))).trim();
String Time = (line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(",")+2, line.length())).trim();
//System.out.println(TestName + " " + Time);
data.put(TestName, Time);
}
```

This works fine. However, I'm not sure of the best way to go about getting all unique values and running the calculation. I don't need to use a Map, it was what just popped into my head. Does anyone know how to do something like this?

## CSV file sample:

```
Test Name, Thread No, Run No, Time(s)
Opening login page, 0, 0, 1.8869998455047607
Opening login page, 1, 0, 2.246999979019165
Opening login page, 2, 0, 2.1710000038146973
Logging in as regular user, 1, 0, 22.009999990463257
Logging in as regular user, 1, 0, 22.009999990463257
Logging in as regular user, 1, 0, 22.009999990463257
Logging in as lead user, 0, 0, 23.616000175476074
Opening login page, 13, 0, 2.125999927520752
Opening login page, 15, 0, 1.8939998149871826
Logging in as lead user, 3, 0, 20.244999885559082
Logging in as lead user, 2, 0, 23.039999961853027
```

Comment: Not sure if Java is the best suited language for this. You might be better off using a simple scripting language instead.

Comment: Another option - if it has to be Java - could be using JavaDB (which is included in the current SDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) to store the values and performing some simple SQL queries against it. It's all in-memory AFAIK, no further DB installation/administration required.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I have already parsed the CSV and stored it successfully in my Map object. My problem is that I don't know how I can get the metrics I want from it. I need to somehow group by TestName and then gather things like min time, max time, average time, etc... I'll look into some of the suggestions here. Does anyone have any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing csv, refer
http://www.java-examples.com/parse-csv-file-using-stringtokenizer-example

You can use Set as u need unique values.
For stats, use functions of Collections class like Collections.max(hashSetObj).

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of SQL on top of a CSV file by using some CSV JDBC driver like [this one](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) or [this one](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_csv.htm). Once you have loaded such a driver, you can perform whatever type of query you need by using ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. For counting the frequency of phrases you could use a [HashTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) that uses the phrase as the key and increments by one each time the phrase is encountered.
2. You could make your life a little easier by using a CSV parser [library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).